# SQL Count Query Using Non-Index Column

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I have a query similar to this, where I need to find the number of transactions a specific customer had within a time frame:

```
select customer_id, count(transactions)
from transactions
where customer_id = 'FKJ90838485'
and purchase_date between '01-JAN-13' and '31-AUG-13'
group by customer_id
```

The table transactions is not indexed on customer_id but rather another field called transaction_id. Customer_ID is character type while transaction_id is numeric.

'accounting_month' field is also indexed.. this field just stores the month that transactions occured... ie, purchase_date = '03-MAR-13' would have accounting_month = '01-MAR-13'

The transactions table has about 20 million records in the time frame from '01-JAN-13' and '31-AUG-13'

When I run the above query, it has taken more than 40 minutes to come back, any ideas or tips?

Comment: Are you able to add a covering index?

Comment: Don't think so, I only have query/select rights

Comment: @user1683776 I assume the transaction_id column is of IDENTITY type, and it is indexed, correct?

Comment: This query - as it is - would give error. Add the actual query if you want a real answer. Although I'd say any answer would involve adding an index - which you can't do.

Comment: Best index to add would probably be a composite on (customer_id, purchase_date). But as ypercube said, your query gives an error...you have an aggregate function, but no 'group by' clause...and why 'count(transactions)' instead of 'count(*)'? Is there even a 'transactions' column?

Comment: Contact the Database administrator.  Request that he add an index on CustomerId.

Comment: Please do not rely on implicit data type conversion. `'01-JAN-13'` is a string literal and not a date. This will fail if run from a computer with different NLS settings.

Comment: Make your between datetime variables, add index... done.

Comment: @ypercube added the group by... must've gotten lost in sample code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its just a sample code, I use datetime variables in the acutal code i'm using.

Comment: And this date field is indexed or not?

Comment: @FabienTheSolution this one is not... there is however an 'accounting_month' field that is.. this field just stores the month that transactions occured... ie, purchase_date = '03-MAR-13' would have accounting_month = '01-MAR-13'

Comment: Thanks for the answer....I edited my answer to take this in consideration

Comment: Over 40 minutes for just 20 million rows sounds extreme.  How large is the transaction table, in bytes?  Look at `select bytes/1024/1024/1024 gb from dba_segments where segment_name = 'TRANSACTIONS';`.  You should also post the explain plan for the query.

Answer (score 4):

As others have already commented, the best is to add an index that will cover the query, So:

- Contact the Database administrator and request that they add an index on `(customer_id, purchase_date)` because the query is doing a table scan otherwise.

Sidenotes:

- Use date and not string literals (you may know that and do it already, still noted here for future readers)
- You don't have to put the `customer_id` in the `SELECT` list and if you remove it from there, it can be removed from the `GROUP BY` as well so the query becomes:

  ```
  select count(*) as number_of_transactions
  from transactions
  where customer_id = 'FKJ90838485'
    and purchase_date between DATE '2013-01-01' and DATE '2013-08-31' ;
  ```
- If you don't have a `WHERE` condition on `customer_id`, you can have it in the `GROUP BY` and the `SELECT` list to write a query that will count number of transactions for every customer. And the above suggested index will help this, too:

  ```
  select customer_id, count(*) as number_of_transactions
  from transactions
  where purchase_date between DATE '2013-01-01' and DATE '2013-08-31' 
  group by customer_id  ;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea that came up to me. It might work, try running it and see if it is an improvement over what you currently have.

I'm trying to use the `transaction_id`, which you've said is indexed, as much as possible.

```
WITH min_transaction (tran_id)
AS (
   SELECT MIN(transaction_ID)
   FROM TRANSACTIONS
   WHERE
      CUSTOMER_ID = 'FKJ90838485'
      AND purchase_date >= '01-JAN-13'
   ), max_transaction (tran_id)
AS (
   SELECT MAX(transaction_ID)
   FROM TRANSACTIONS
   WHERE 
      CUSTOMER_ID = 'FKJ90838485'
      AND purchase_date <= '31-AUG-13'
   )
SELECT customer_id, count(transaction_id)
FROM transactions
WHERE
   transaction_id BETWEEN min_transaction.tran_id AND max_transaction.tran_id
GROUP BY customer_ID
```

Comment: why all the `1 = 1`s ?

Comment: I would expect that to run even slower because I would assume that the two CTEs won't be able to use an index and thus you'll wind up with two table scans instead of one. And besides the `1=1` is totally useless (I know it's a custom habit for generated code, but in hand-written code it's simply unnecessary)

Comment: I was also thinking along these lines. If you are not able to add new indexes then see if there is any way you can use the existing index on customer_ID to get a distinct list (or range as above) of transaction_ids.

Comment: @CharlesBretana Just out of habbit.

Comment: 1=1 is a neat shortcut to allow you to comment in and out parametera without having to resolve missings ANDs and such

Comment: @rhollyer That is why I use it.

Comment: There's nothing in your answer that describes why you think this is an improvement, or what your idea is.

Comment: @user814064 I'm trying to use the transaction_id column, which I know is indexed, as much as possible.

Comment: But to get the minimum and maximum transaction IDs you still have to search by customer and date, so you are now performing 2 table scans so you can use an index. You are also assuming chronological entry to the table (i.e I can't insert today a transaction from a year ago, that would have a higher transaction ID than a transaction from today. Finally the end result would have more customers in than just the required customer, so a different result from the query in the question.

Comment: And what if customer `FKJ90838485` don't have any transaction on 01-JAN-13 or on 01-AUG-13?

Comment: @FabienTheSolution That IS what he is searching for. If the customer doesn't have any transactions than that is the answer.

Comment: If the customer don't have any transaction on january 1st, this will not return any ID : `SELECT MIN(transaction_ID)   FROM TRANSACTIONS
   WHERE
      CUSTOMER_ID = 'FKJ90838485'
      AND purchase_date = '01-JAN-13'`

Comment: Ok...but now you are looking for ALL transactions before '31-AUG-13'...btw...since the OP doesn't answer for now....we can only presume what is the best approach :)

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Yes, I am looking for his earliest and latest transaction in the `1st January` and `31st August` interval.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36884/discussion-between-radu-gheorghiu-and-fabien-thesolution)

Comment: @FabianTheSolution to clarify I just need transactions for customer `FKJ90838485` for that given time frame... it's not set in stone as I could want it from `'01-MAR-13' to '31-JUN-13'` but I appreciate all the input!

Comment: @user1683776 I know :) ... my comment was related to the previous code and was about the code itself...before the editing...

Answer (score 0):

May be this will run faster since it look at the `transaction_id` for the range instead of the `purchase_date`. I also take in consideration that `accounting_month` is indexed :

```
select customer_id, count(*)
from transactions
where customer_id = 'FKJ90838485'
and transaction_id between (select min(transaction_id)
                            from transactions
                           where accounting_month = '01-JAN-13' 
                           )  and
                           (select max(transaction_id)
                            from transactions
                           where accounting_month = '01-AUG-13' 
                           ) 
group by customer_id
```

May be you can also try :

```
select customer_id, count(*)
from transactions
where customer_id = 'FKJ90838485'
and accounting_month between '01-JAN-13' and '01-AUG-13'
group by customer_id
```

Comment: As that is Oracle, most probably there is no column named `"transaction_id"` (only one name `transaction_id` or `"TRANSACTION_ID"`)

Comment: Assuming transactions can only ever be entered in chronological order.

Comment: @GarethD We can only assume with what we have from the OP

Comment: In addition you still have to do 2 table scans on transactions to get the min and max IDs.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What do you mean? The OP stated that there is a column name `transaction_id`

Comment: @GarethD...may be...but only for 2 days, not 8 months :)

Comment: You will have MUCH more transactions to go over (all of the other customers included) with the primary select.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu But I have to...since we don't know if the customer have a purchase on january 1st...

Comment: As I said: `transaction_id` is not the same as `"transaction_id"` in Oracle. The double quotes make it case sensitive. But unquoted names are folded to uppercase in Oracle. So if `transcation_id` works for the OP the real column name is `TRANSACTION_ID` and `"transaction_id"` will **not** work for the OP. See here for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab2ce/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name...you wrote " if transcation_id works for the OP ".... we don't know...he didn't use it in the query...and it's because I create the table in [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01b0f/27/0) and double quote was added to fields name...but thanks...I was not really aware of that :) (I work with SQLServer and MySQL, but not with Oracle)